# Run jQuery code inside $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I have a simple code that opens a dialog using Angular Material.
Now in that dialog I have a wysiwyg texteditor which is written in jQuery. To activate it I need jQuery to run a codesnippet. How do I do that?

This is the code for opening the dialog

```
$scope.OpenPostData = function(ev, id) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: "PostData",
      templateUrl: 'templates/PostData.php?id='+id+"&t="+Math.random(),
      locals: { 
        data: $scope.data
      },
      clickOutsideToClose: true
    }).then( function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
};
```

In that template I have a `<textarea id="trumbowyg"></textarea>`

I need to run this jQuery code on that textarea.

```
$("#trumbowyg").trumbowyg({
    removeformatPasted: true,
    lang: "sv",
    fullscreenable: false,
    btns: ['viewHTML', 'btnGrp-design', 'link', 'btnGrp-lists', 'insertImage']
});
```

I've tried using "`compile`" function but I don't think its built in on `$mdDialog`. I've also tried to add `<script></script>` in that file but I dont think AngularJS directives run `<script>` inside templates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the PostData controller??

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Avoid using anything that relies on jQuery whenever possible (in an Angular app). There are plenty of text editors out there that are built for Angular. 2. If you have to use something that relies on jQuery, see if someone's already produced an Angular wrapper for it. In this case, you can check out [this Angular directive for Trumbowyg](https://github.com/lizardK/trumbowyg-ng). The hard work is already done for it, you just need to use it.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein gave the best answer I would +1 if it were not just a comment. Angular directive is the best way to go. Angular controller should NEVER manage View, Directive manages View. This rule save time and pain in this nice Angular JS world. Have fun dev time!